# Google Cloud BigQuery is not refreshing?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Excuse me for maybe a not very precise question, but I just need to check if I am missing something or it really is some kind of problem with Google Cloud (GC) BigQuery.

I've got this Java program that reads from a website and publish the data into a GC Pub/Sub Topic; a pipeline is conveniently up, pulling the message from Pub/Sub and sending it to BigQuery via the template job offered in GC Dataflow. In the end, a DataStudio dashboard is getting the data from the BigQuery table and building up its charts and all...

The thing is, all the process is working fine: I can see the resulting dashboard being populated correctly, BUT I cannot see the data in the table in BigQuery, even after refreshing the whole page. Sometimes the results show on the following day (!).

Is it me forgetting something, or is it GC BigQuery in a beta release being incomplete?

Comment: Could you define how you "see" the data? Are you running a query? (btw BQ is not in beta)

Comment: Just don't see the data in the table when clicking the Preview button. Maybe queries might work, as DataStudio does with those data; but I looked for something more direct.

Comment: that Preview functionality is just a UI thing and it's great to quickly inspect the table, not to accurately query it. This question cannot be answered as it's not about a broken service

Comment: I see... Still, it is quite confusing when the Preview is not showing anything, or even announcing that 'Table contains zero records', as it does. In this way, this quick inspection I wanted for my table results in not being that great at all...
Thanks, @Pentium10. I will leave the question open for some time though, just in case there is any further ideas.

Comment: create an issue for this preview thing, maybe someone from Google will be able to tune it, otherwise this Stackoverflow is just a community: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: Issue submitted. Thanks again. I will report here any significant answer they give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pentium10 said, the GUI is just for quick previews. It does take some time to update itself. If you want to check if the data is in the table do a query.